# Оператор INNER JOIN и подсчет максимального значения

Tags: sql, sql-server

Не знаю как реализовать описанную ниже операцию на SQL Server. Чтобы не вдаваться в особенности моей базы данных, приведу похожий, но абстрактный пример.

Допустим, что база данных состоит из двух таблиц: сотрудники и отделы. Каждый сотрудник состоит в одном отделе. В каждом отделе может быть много сотрудников. В таблице сотрудников среди множества полей есть поле с заработной платой. Собственно мне нужно вывести список всех сотрудников. Для каждого сотрудника вывести название отдела, зарабоную плату, а также **максимальную заработную плату в его отделе**.

Собственно сложности возникли только с **последним полем** (MaxSalaryInDepartment).

Пример выполнения запроса:

```
| EmployeeID | DepartmentName | EmployeeSalary | MaxSalaryInDepartment |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | A              | 10             | 20                    |
| 3          | A              | 15             | 20                    |
| 4          | A              | 20             | 20                    |
| 2          | B              | 15             | 15                    |
| 5          | C              | 30             | 35                    |
| 6          | C              | 35             | 35                    |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По идее такой пример должен работать:

```
select EmployeeID, DepartmentName, EmployeeSalary, 
    max(EmployeeSalary) OVER (PARTITION BY DepartmentName) as MaxSalaryInDepartment
```

Только надо учитывать, что результат в таком случае будет браться из итоговой выдачи, т.е. допустим если Вы в запрос добавите что-нибудь вроде `where EmployeeID = 10`, то такой запрос уже не вернет корретный результат. В таком случае надо будет использовать вложенный запрос для рассчета максимальных значений по отделам.